# Why am I getting a InitializeReferenceTypeStaticFieldsInline warning from FxCop?

Tags: .net, vb.net, fxcop

I have this:

```
Public Class Foo
    Private Shared ReadOnly machineName As String
    Private Shared ReadOnly userName As String = Environment.UserName
    Private Shared ReadOnly domainName As String
    Private Shared ReadOnly events As New List(Of ManualResetEvent)()

    Shared Sub New()

        AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit,
            New EventHandler(AddressOf Wait)
        'wait for all tasks to complete before the process terminates

        Try
            machineName = Environment.MachineName
        Catch ex As InvalidOperationException
            machineName = ""
        End Try

        Try
            domainName = Environment.UserDomainName
        Catch ex As InvalidOperationException
            domainName = ""
        Catch ex As PlatformNotSupportedException
            domainName = ""
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

What is FxCop telling me to do here?

```
CriticalWarning, Certainty 90, for InitializeReferenceTypeStaticFieldsInline
{
    Target       : #.cctor()  (IntrospectionTargetMember)
    Location     : file://blah/blah/blah
    Resolution   : "Initialize all static fields in 'Namespace' 
                   when those fields are declared and remove the explicit 
                   static constructor."
    Help         : http://msdn2.microsoft.com/library/ms182275(VS.90).aspx  (String)
    Category     : Microsoft.Performance  (String)
    CheckId      : CA1810  (String)
    RuleFile     : Performance Rules  (String)
    Info         : "Static fields should be initialized when declared. 
                   Initializing static data in explicit static constructors 
                   results in less performant code."
    Created      : 5/26/2015 9:46:09 PM  (DateTime)
    LastSeen     : 5/26/2015 9:46:09 PM  (DateTime)
    Status       : Active  (MessageStatus)
    Fix Category : NonBreaking  (FixCategories)
}
```

Comment: I think the issue is not in the code you posted. Can you include some context (and, specifically, highlight the full line of code the message is raised for)? You say you're initializing a variable but don't show the scope of the variable or where you're initializing it, which is what the message alludes to as the problem...

Comment: @DanPuzey, whoops. You're right....

Answer (score 0):

The detailed message of the rule is pretty explicit. In short: initialize all of your static (Shared) variables inline where they are declared (like you do with userName) and get rid of the static constructor (Shared New) because it might be slower.